# running pyspark.mllib on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to link Spark in python. Codes bellow is `test.py`, and I put it under `~/spark/python`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt")
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

And I run `python test.py` get this error messge:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '/home/user/spark/lib_managed/jars' does not exist.
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:249)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildClassPath(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:208)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildJavaCommand(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:195)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
  File "/home/user/spark/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/home/user/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 245, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/home/user/spark/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

I move `test.py` to `~/spark`, and I get:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

I clone Spark project from the official website.
OS system: Ubuntu
Java version: 1.7.0_79
Python version: 2.7.11

Can anyone give me some tips to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark programs must be submitted through "Spark-submit". More info: [Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

You should try running: `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit test.py` instead of `python test.py`.

Comment: Thanks! In this way, I can write my own python file. And it run smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824818/what-to-set-spark-home-to) out if you haven't set `SPARK_HOME` and add its lib to `PYTHONPATH`.

Also,

> I clone Spark project from the official website

This is not recommended as it could give a lot of dependency issues. You could try [download](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) a pre-built version with Hadoop, then test it in the local mode with instructions [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: Thanks! I just run the local mode, and test it successfully. However, I don't really understand the difference in it.